# Reconstruct image from final convolutional layer

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I have trained a image deblurring network. I have used Euclidean loss between reconstructed image and groundTruth image as my loss function. I get a euclidean loss of about 3.0 for a image of size 249x249x3( size of ground truth and reconstructed image.)

I used a gaussianBlurr with kernel of size 11x11 for deblurring the fine images. I used about 15k training images. My final convolutional layer has num_output: 3. So it produces three feature maps. I want to generate an RGB image from these the output of these three filters.

I am unable to construct the image from the output of final convolutional layer.

Till now I have the following code for reconstruction of final image, but this code is not able to generate good image.

```
inputBlob = net.blobs.keys()[0]
outputBlob = net.blobs.keys()[-1]

print inputBlob
print outputBlob

out = net.blobs[outputBlob].data
print out.shape
# print type(out)
# print out
out = out.reshape(out.shape[1], out.shape[2], out.shape[3])
print out.shape
out = out.transpose(1, 2, 0)
print out.shape
# out /= 0.004
# out[:,:,0] += 103.939
# out[:,:,1] += 116.779   
# out[:,:,2] += 123.68
# print out

# print type(out)
# print out.shape

scipy.misc.imsave('out.jpg', out)
```

The commented code includes the debug steps. And also I have tried to denormalize the image and add the mean values. But it also did not give any good result. I tried this step because I did mean subtraction and normalization before forwarding the input to network.

Any links, helps and suggestions will be appreciated. Following is my train_val.prototxt file:

```
name: "DeblurrNet"

layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  data_param {
    source: "/home/gpu/Programs/Dharma/DeblurrNet/codes/train_lmdb"
    batch_size: 1
    backend: LMDB
  }
  transform_param {
    mean_file: "/home/gpu/Programs/Dharma/DeblurrNet/data/mean.binaryproto"
    scale: 0.004
    crop_size: 255
    # fixed_crop: true
  }
  include: { phase: TRAIN }
}

layer {
  name: "labels"
  type: "Data"
  top: "labels"
  data_param {
    source: "/home/gpu/Programs/Dharma/DeblurrNet/codes/train_label_lmdb"
    batch_size: 1
    backend: LMDB
  }
  transform_param {
    mean_file: "/home/gpu/Programs/Dharma/DeblurrNet/data/label_mean.binaryproto"
    scale: 0.004
    crop_size: 249
    # fixed_crop: true
  }
  include: { phase: TRAIN }
}


layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  data_param {
    source: "/home/gpu/Programs/Dharma/DeblurrNet/codes/val_lmdb"
    backend: LMDB
    batch_size: 1
  }
  transform_param {
    mean_file: "/home/gpu/Programs/Dharma/DeblurrNet/data/mean.binaryproto"
    scale: 0.004
    crop_size: 255
    # fixed_crop: true
  }
  include: { phase: TEST }
}

layer {
  name: "labels"
  type: "Data"
  top: "labels"
  data_param {
    source: "/home/gpu/Programs/Dharma/DeblurrNet/codes/val_label_lmdb"
    backend: LMDB
    batch_size: 1   
  }
  transform_param {
    mean_file: "/home/gpu/Programs/Dharma/DeblurrNet/data/label_mean.binaryproto"
    scale: 0.004
    crop_size: 249
    # fixed_crop: true
  }
  include: { phase: TEST }
}


layer {
  name: "CONVX_1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "CONVX_1"

 param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {

    kernel_size: 5
    num_output: 128
    stride: 1
    pad: 0
    # group: 1

    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "RELU_1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "CONVX_1"
  top: "CONVX_1"
}
layer {
  name: "CONVX_2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "CONVX_1"
  top: "CONVX_2"

 param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {

    kernel_size: 1
    num_output: 128
    stride: 1
    pad: 0
    # group: 1

    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "RELU_2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "CONVX_2"
  top: "CONVX_2"
}
layer {
  name: "CONVX_3"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "CONVX_2"
  top: "CONVX_3"

 param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {

    kernel_size: 1
    num_output: 128
    stride: 1
    pad: 0
    # group: 1

    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "RELU_3"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "CONVX_3"
  top: "CONVX_3"
}
layer {
  name: "CONVX_4"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "CONVX_3"
  top: "CONVX_4"

 param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {

    kernel_size: 1
    num_output: 128
    stride: 1
    pad: 0
    # group: 1

    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "RELU_4"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "CONVX_4"
  top: "CONVX_4"
}
layer {
  name: "CONVX_5"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "CONVX_4"
  top: "CONVX_5"

 param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {

    kernel_size: 1
    num_output: 128
    stride: 1
    pad: 0
    # group: 1

    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "RELU_5"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "CONVX_5"
  top: "CONVX_5"
}
layer {
  name: "CONVX_6"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "CONVX_5"
  top: "CONVX_6"

 param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {

    kernel_size: 3
    num_output: 64
    stride: 1
    pad: 0
    # group: 1

    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "RELU_6"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "CONVX_6"
  top: "CONVX_6"
}
layer {
  name: "CONVX_7"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "CONVX_6"
  top: "CONVX_7"

 param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {

    kernel_size: 1
    num_output: 16
    stride: 1
    pad: 0
    # group: 1

    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "RELU_7"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "CONVX_7"
  top: "CONVX_7"
}
layer {
  name: "CONVX_8"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "CONVX_7"
  top: "CONVX_8"

 param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {

    kernel_size: 1
    num_output: 3
    stride: 1
    pad: 0
    # group: 4

    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "EuclideanLoss"
  top: "loss"
  bottom: "CONVX_8"
  bottom: "labels"
}
```

For LMDB creation, I used the create_lmdbs.sh file from the imagenet example in caffe. I turned off shuffling as I need pairs without shuffling for input and label.

Here first one is the original image, second is the blurred version, and third is the reconstructed image from CNN.

[image: Original] 
[image: gaussianBlurred] 
[image]

Comment: what is your input "ground truth" and how do  you set the loss layer? If you compare pixel to pixel with the "clean" image, your net should output a "clean" image.

Comment: @shai: my input ground truth is images from pascal voc. They are fine images. I generate blur images on my own using gaussian blurr. I used the EuclideanLoss from caffe. loss seems to converge. But I am not able to reconstuct the single image from the three outputs of final convolutional layer.

Comment: do you subtract mean, swap channels, `transpose` or scale the **ground truth** images? to interpret the **output** you must follow the transformations you did on the **ground truth** images (and not the inputs). Do you understand why? BTW, your loss converged to ~3.0. Is it pixel-wise loss? what is the scale of the pixel-values of the prediction/ground truth? If you have average pixel-wise error of 3.0 when GT/output range is [0..1] then you basically have random output...

Comment: @shai: I will upload my train_val.prototxt file. I give the mean.binaryproto file. I think caffe does the mean subtraction and normalization (I am not sure.). My images are scaled to range of [0..1].

Comment: @shai: sorry shai. I was using hingeloss instead of euclidean loss. Now I changed to euclidean loss and trained again. But the loss seems to fluctuate around 200-1k, which is very high. I have set the learning rate to 0.0001 and and solver to adam solver.

Comment: It seems that in you output you have channels RGB -> BGR swapped.

Comment: @ImanolLuengo: You are right. I swapped the channels. Looks good than previous one.

Answer (score 1):

Your input layers do cropping:

```
transform_param {
  mean_file: "/home/gpu/Programs/Dharma/DeblurrNet/data/mean.binaryproto"
  scale: 0.004
  crop_size: 255   # <---- crop
}
```

If you read **carefully** the [comment in `caffe.proto`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L419-L420), it says

> Specify if we would like to **randomly** crop an image.

Now here's what's going on on your net, you have an input image that you **randomly** crop to 255x255, while on the other hand, you have the "clean" (ground-truth) image that is **randomly** cropped to 249x249. There's no correlation between these two crops! You might as well get the top left part of the noisy input image with the bottom right part of the noise-free ground truth image. What do you expect your net to learn under these settings??

Comment: Thank you - I will remove this crop layer and train again.

Comment: I trained again. Still I am getting a high loss of around 600. I have uploaded the original, blurred, and reconstructed version above. I am not sure where I did wrong. I tried with hdf5 data layer as well, but not able to converge the euclidean loss.

Comment: @Dharma does your output prediction make more sense now?

Comment: ya - It makes more sense now. But still not able to converge the loss. I have also tried the custom SSIM loss using python layer, the output is similar. The loss is really low, about 0.03 if I use SSIM loss. But the output is similar to using euclidean loss. I have attached the images in question, please have a look at them.

Comment: shai - What would be wrong in this configuration? I am not able to converge the euclidean loss. could you please point me in the right direction.

Comment: @Dharma I'm afraid I do not have the answer for that. You'll have to do some research here...

Comment: Shai- Thank you. I will try to find the reason. and inform you if I solve it. I hope you will suggest me if you get any idea about the cause.